# Dynamically transpose Row to Column in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am looking the dynamically transpose row to column in oracle.i have tried to transpose using pivot or with the help of decode but there i need to provide the hard coding column name as here i have given 'Round 1 (AJM-15)' and 'Round 2 (AJM-15)' in the below query But I am trying to achieve these value dynamically is it possible.

```
SELECT CC.WARD,SUM(DECODE(CC.QTR, 'Round 1 (AJM-15)',round(CC.METRIC_VALUE,3), 0)) AS "Round 1 (AJM-15)",
               SUM(DECODE(CC.QTR, 'Round 2 (AJM-15)',round(CC.METRIC_VALUE,3), 0)) AS "Round 2 (AJM-15)"

             From   (
SELECT SUM(DENO) AS METRIC_VALUE,CENTRE,QTR,WARD FROM (
       select CENTRE,QTR,WARD,sum(COUNTS) AS DENO from FACT_AVF_RESP
        where 
         outlet_type in (SELECT distinct outlet_type
                       FROM FACT_AVF_RESP m
                       WHERE outlet_type IN (SELECT distinct outlet_type FROM FACT_AVF_RESP)
                       AND 'All' = 'All'
                       UNION
                       SELECT distinct outlet_type
                       FROM FACT_AVF_RESP n
                       WHERE outlet_type ='All'
                             )  and
        CENTRE= 'AHMEDABAD' and 
        gpi in (SELECT distinct gpi
                       FROM FACT_AVF_RESP o
                       WHERE gpi IN (SELECT distinct gpi FROM FACT_AVF_RESP)
                       AND 'All' = 'All'
                       UNION
                       SELECT distinct gpi
                       FROM FACT_AVF_RESP o
                       WHERE gpi ='All'
                             ) AND
       QTR in (select distinct p.qtr from fact_avf_nd p where p.qtr 
                                          between 'Round 1 (AJM-15)' and 'Round 2 (AJM-15)') 

        group by  QTR,CENTRE,WARD    
  order by QTR
  )group by  CENTRE,QTR,WARD
  ORDER BY QTR,WARD)cc
  group by CC.WARD;
```

On the between condition i have to provide from and to parameter based on provide parameter value my qtr column values will come and that column value should be transpose dynamically.

Comment: you want to read about PIVOT: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: In the pivot also we have to define the column name hard coded ?but my problem is here i am looking dynamically .My QTR value will be coming dynamically based on provided parameter in between operator

Comment: oh, then you may want to read this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:5312784100346298561

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to achieve this without using dynamic sql.

OCI and JDBC api allows the caller to describe columns of the query, before it is executed. What you want is not deterministic i.e. Oracle might notice that there are additional columns to be added while evaluating the query. This violates the API contract.

Each query result must have fixed number of columns defind regardless of data nature.
There is also construct `PIVOT XML`, which can might do what you want. There will be only one column added having dynamically added columns concatenated in a XML document.